# PHP Glob function to find Controller files

Tags: php, glob, filepattern

I try to find all the controller files of a java code repository in php script.(Lets say CustomerController.java for example)

Here is the solution i have tried to achieve this goal:

```
$fileScan = glob($currentDirectory . "**/*Controller.java");
```

But it returns nothing. I have also tried different combinations like:

```
"**Controller*.java", "*/*Controller*.java" etc.
```

But not luck.

Am i missing something here about glob function?

Comment: what's the `$currentDirectory` and what is the actual path to your controllers from the webserver ie. `/var/www/yourcode/controllers/`

Comment: `glob` is not that powerful in PHP. You can specify patterns like `*/*/*Class.php` but `**` does not have any extended effect.

Comment: If you know the platform PHP is running on and system access is not locked, you can find files much faster using shell commands. I even wrote some OS switch in the past to use `find` on iX or `dir /r` on Windows or fallback to PHP when system access is not available. This makes sense when frequently scanning large file systems.

Comment: Unfortunately system access is locked. I trigger the script as an admin service user.

Comment: If you can specify a max depth, another simple glob approach could be to take (or generate) a pattern like `glob("../../{,*/,*/*/,*/*/*/}*Controller*.java", GLOB_BRACE);`

Comment: I've added this as an alternative answer to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

```
<?php
function rsearch($folder, $pattern) {
    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
    $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
    $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
    $fileList = array();
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
    }
    return $fileList;
}
?>
```

Comment: You should flag a question as duplicate instead of just copying other's answer 1:1.

Comment: Also, note that behavior can vary between windows and linux, when using this class. Would definitely check docs: "On Windows, you will get the files ordered by name. On Linux they are not ordered."

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. It will find the files with "Controller.java"

```
foreach (glob("*Controller.java") as $filename) 
{
    echo $filename;
}
```

Comment: Not any difference from my first attempt. The point is, all the file patterns may be deep inside the directory. Thats why i need to recursively iterate through.